# Самый простой фильтр и массив на js

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Доброго времени суток!

Не совсем точно, видимо, объяснила, свою проблему. Поэтому обновляю вопрос:

Есть ссылки `.answer-list-name`, при нажатии на которые, все `.thumbnail`, не содержащие такой `.answer-name`, становятся невидимыми. А при нажатии, на "Все ответы" - все становятся видимыми. Вопрос в том, как правильно сравнивать значения нажимаемого `.answer-list-name` и всех имеющихся `.answer-name`.
Надеюсь, понятно объяснила. :)

```js
var answers = [{
  "answer_name": "Ария Старк",
  "strong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}, {
  "answer_name": "Джейме Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}];



for (var ans in answers) {
  var answerList = document.getElementById("answers-list");
  var strongsTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  var newAnswerName = document.createElement('li');
  newAnswerName.innerHTML = "<a class='answer-list-name'>" + answers[ans].answer_name + "</a>";
  answerList.appendChild(newAnswerName);

  /*Сильные стороны*/
  var newStrong = document.createElement('div');
  newStrong.className = "answer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3";

  newStrong.innerHTML = "<div href='#' class='thumbnail'> <h5 class='answer-name'>" + answers[ans].answer_name + "</h5><p class='answer-text'>" + answers[ans].strong + "</div>";
  strongsTo.appendChild(newStrong);



}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="answers-list" id="answers-list">
  <li class="active"><a class="answer-list-name" href="">Все ответы</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="row answers" id="strongs">

</div>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю у вас текстовое поле куда вы вводите текст, все <h1> в которых этого текста нет скрываются вместе с нижележащим текстом, так?

Comment: покажите как получается. В итоге вы хотите решение на js без каких либо дополнительных библиотек, или все-таки на angularjs?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без использования jQuery
1) вынести построение списка ответов в отдельную функцию, например

```
function createStrongs(strongs) {
  var strongsTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  strongsTo.innerHTML = strongs.map(function(answer) {
    return '<div class="answer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">\
               <div class="thumbnail">\
                    <h5 class="answer-name">' + answer.answer_name + '</h5>\
                    <p class="answer-text">' + answer.strong + '</p>\
               </div>\
            </div>'
  }).join('');
}
```

2) вынести построение списка пунктов меню в отдельную функцию и, так как список не меняется, то можно сразу навесить обработчик по клику на эти элементы, например

```
function createMenu(links) {
  var answerList = document.getElementById("answers-list");
  answerList.innerHTML += links.map(function(link) {
    return '<li>\
                <a class="answer-list-name">' + link.answer_name + '</a>\
            </li>'
  }).join('');

  //выбираем все элементы с классом .answer-list-name
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.answer-list-name'), function(menuItem) {//бежим по всем
    menuItem.addEventListener('click', function() {//добавляем обработчик для клика
      var selected = this.innerHTML;//проверяем что кликнули
      if (selected == "Все ответы") //если все
        createStrongs(answers);//показываем все
      else//иначе
        createStrongs(answers.filter(function(ans) {//фильтруем исходный массив
          return ans.answer_name == selected;
        }));
    });
  });
}
```

```js
var answers = [{
  "answer_name": "Ария Старк",
  "strong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}, {
  "answer_name": "Джейме Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}];

function createStrongs(strongs) {
  var strongsTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  strongsTo.innerHTML = strongs.map(function(answer) {
    return '<div class="answer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">\
               <div class="thumbnail">\
                    <h5 class="answer-name">' + answer.answer_name + '</h5>\
                    <p class="answer-text">' + answer.strong + '</p>\
               </div>\
            </div>'
  }).join('');
}
function createMenu(links){
  var answerList = document.getElementById("answers-list");
  answerList.innerHTML += links.map(function(link){
    return '<li>\
                <a class="answer-list-name">'+link.answer_name+'</a>\
            </li>'
  }).join('');
  
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.answer-list-name')).forEach(function(menuItem){
    menuItem.addEventListener('click',function(){
      var selected = this.innerHTML;
      if(selected == "Все ответы") 
        createStrongs(answers);
      else
        createStrongs(answers.filter(function(ans){
              return ans.answer_name == selected;
          }))
      });
    });
  
}
createMenu(answers);
createStrongs(answers)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="answers-list" id="answers-list">
  <li class="active"><a class="answer-list-name" href="#">Все ответы</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="row answers" id="strongs">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос в том как фильтровать массив объектов, то:

```
var db = [{h : 'Заголовок', t : 'Текст'}, {h : 'Заголовок', t : 'Текст'}];
function filter(str) {
  return db.filter(function(el) {
    return el.h.indexOf(str) !== -1;
  });
}
```

Если фильтр на html странице:

```js
function filter(str) {
  var headers = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(headers, function(el) {
    if (el.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}

var inp = document.querySelector('#filterInp');
inp.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  filter(inp.value);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hidden+p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filterInp" />

<h1>First header</h1>
<p>Text 1, text 1, text 1, text 1.</p>

<h1>Second header</h1>
<p>Text 2, text 2, text 2, text 2.</p>

<h1>Third header</h1>
<p>Text 3, text 3, text 3, text 3.</p>
```

Comment: ничего себе попроще :-)

Comment: @Grundy Ну я воспринимаю подключение Angular'а - более сложным для этой задачи методом. Не в количестве своего кода, а в количестве ненужного для этой задачи кода из библиотек. Тем более если посмотреть на метки и вопрос, то там и подразумевается требование не использовать дополнительные библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, я не до конца правильно понял, какой ожидается результат, но знаю AngularJS могу подсказать одну интересную конструкцию:

Выводим всё, что есть в массиве:
Имеем массив:

```
var list = [   {
    code: 1,
    name: 'list-item-1'   },   {
    code: 2,
    name: 'list-item-2'   } ];
```

Выводим его значения:

```
<input ng-model="query" />
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in filteredList = (list | filter: query)" id={{item.id}}>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

`input` будет фильтровать весь список.

Остальное дело техники.
Имей введу, что в `filteredList`  ты будешь иметь отфильтрованный массив,
а в `list` у тебя будет оригинальный массив.

Comment: _При нажатии на фильтр_

Comment: $scope.turnOnFilter = function () {

Comment: я имел ввиду - у вас поле ввода, _<input ng-model="query" />_ а топик стартер хотел, чтобы это был список ссылок, по которым можно щелкнуть